# Draw equal number of list elements from python list

Tags: python, loops, iterable

I have collected a data stored in 1000 python lists. The data are float numbers. Lists are of different lengths. Smallest list is 23 datapoints long the largest is 173.

I'd like to pick from each of those lists 23 datapoints however I'd like them to be more or less equally distributed in terms of index position.

Therefore from smallest list it would be each element.

From list with 46 elements it would be every 2nd element and so on as it got bigger.

The challange here is obviously those like 40 elements or 91 elements which really does not divide equally and random would really not give me equal distribution along index.

Tried itertools.islice with start,stop and step but really can't figure out as the step size must vary and I'm ending up with cases where I actually pull 22 or 24 etc.

Appreciate your help
E

Comment: Could you please provide a sample input and output. It helps in our understanding the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-line function to return a list of n items from a_list, as evenly spaced as possible.  You probably want to add some error handling, for example if n < len(a_list).

```
def select_n(a_list, n):
    return [a_list[len(a_list) * k // n] for k in range(n)]

print(select_n(list(range(150)), 23))
print(select_n(list(range(23)), 23))
print(select_n(list(range(45)), 23))
```

Output:

```
[0, 6, 13, 19, 26, 32, 39, 45, 52, 58, 65, 71, 78, 84, 91, 97, 104, 110, 117, 123, 130, 136, 143]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
[0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43]
```

Comment: Working as it should. Much appreciate it!

Comment: Would you mind accepting it so others will know that it's a valid answer?